# Do these two equations have analytical solutions, and if so, what methods can be employed to find them?

Tags: calculus

### Question

For the first equation:$$\cos(y)=\cos(\delta)[(x-x_0)\frac{\sin(\phi)}{\gamma}-\cos(\phi)]$$

For the second equation:$$[(x-x_0)^2\frac{\cos^2(\delta)}{\gamma^2}-\sin^2(\delta)]\frac{\sin^2(Ny)}{\sin^2(y)}+1=0$$Here $x$,$y$ are variables and $\delta$,$x_0$,$\phi$,$\gamma$ are constants. $N$ is a positive integer.

### My attempt

I tried to expand the $\sin(Ny)$ and eliminated $x-x_0$.$$[(\cos(y)+\cos(\phi)\cos(\delta))^2-\sin^2(\delta)\sin^2(\phi)]\sum_{i=0,j=0}^N \begin{pmatrix} N \\ i \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} N \\ j \end{pmatrix}\sin(\frac{i\pi}{2})\sin(\frac{j\pi}{2})\cos^{2N-i-j}(y)\sin^{i+j-2}(y)+\sin^2(\phi)=0 $$But this equation is so complicated, I don't know how to continue

Comment: Try something which is called  "Implicit Function Theorem",

Comment: In general, it doesn't have a closed form solution. for some parameter values you may have closed form solutions.